# Remove Need for Method Prototypes

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, llvm, clang

**Is there a way to remove the need for method prototypes *within an .m file* in Objective-C with LLVM 3.0?**

Right now, just like in plain C, I have to declare a method *above* before I can use it. This seems ancient practice and I see no reason why the compiler couldn't check the file twice, first for getting all methods and second for doing the rest.

I don't just want to turn off compiler warnings! And also autocompletion should see methods from below in the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of no way to disable it, that's generally how c language parsing works.

If you don't want it in the header, try an extension in your .m:

```
@interface MONClass ()
- (void)secretMethod;
@end

@implementation MONClass
...
```

You could file a feature request.

Comment: Probably I will file a feature request then. I've got my prototypes in an extension already, but it's 1) tiresome to write those, 2) it is visual noise and bloats the files, 3) they need updates too when I change the method signature.

Comment: @fabb +1 great. it would be nice to see that someday.

Comment: Filed a feature request at bugreporter.apple.com (id 10335361)

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to turn off all warnings, you can disable just the "Missing Function Prototypes" warning in the build settings of your project.

Comment: Yes, but I **want** missing function prototype warnings. If I turn that off, I could use **any** methods that might or might not exist.